# Send smtp mail laravel notworking

Tags: php, laravel, email, smtp

I have problem in my laravel project and don't know how to solve that
I use mailtrap smtp server to send mail for special user
the mail not sending -  I tried every way ! 
in other new laravel project smtp server working successfully
whats your idea?

here is my Controller:

```
 public function SendContactRespone(ContactReply $request , $id)
{

    Mail::to($request->email)->send(new ContactRespone($request));

    //Contact_form::destroy($id);
    return redirect(route('admin.contact.index'))
        ->with('success', trans('app.err.AnswerEmailed'));
}
```

here is my ContactRespone Mailable

```
    <?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class ContactRespone extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
     return  $this
           ->from(env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS','info@secretpass.ir'))
           ->subject($this->request->subject)
           ->markdown('ui.mails.contactReply')
           ->with([
            'subject' => $this->request->subject,
            'message' => $this->request->text,
        ]);

    }
}
```

env Setting :

```
    MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST="smtp.mailtrap.io"
MAIL_PORT="2525"
MAIL_USERNAME="******"
MAIL_PASSWORD="*******"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=''
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="no-reply@*****.***"
```

after submit the request an email html source save in Storage/log/laravel.log

Answer (score 0):

change to your *`.env`* file configuration for **mailtrap:**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=USERNAME
MAIL_PASSWORD=PASSWORD
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Here you can get **username** and **password** https://mailtrap.io/inboxes you will see the following mailtrap SMTP credentials, Where the username and password are located

After change of .env edit please clear cache: `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: Not working yet ! this setting and this smtp work in other new laravel project

Comment: i didnt recive any error , that say mail sent successfully - i dd() every step and all steps is right - but in my laravel.log after submit i see the mail withe template and maildata ! like when set the mail driver to "log"